# getting info out a key-value field sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, key-value

I try to write a sql query to get some info out a "key-value" field.

- Example of field: `A<1,?,'wfinitiation'=A<1,?,'DocID'=56581,'DocVersion'=0>>`

Is it possible with a SQLfunction to select only the DocID?

- Result in the example would be: 56581

Which function can I use?

Thx

Comment: You label your data as having "fields". That is OO language nomenclature. What format exactly is your data in? Ps. You show several fields as a "field".

Comment: It's a field in the database that contains this info. I would like to select the value DocID in my SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to query the individual values contained in this column you should consider extracting the information and storing it in a relational format. Currently you are violating 1st Normal Form.

That said you can use `substring` and `charindex` for this.

```
DECLARE @key VARCHAR(20)
SET @key='DocID';

DECLARE @Search VARCHAR(30)
SET @Search='''' + @key + '''=';

WITH your_table(col)
     AS (SELECT 'A<1,?,''wfinitiation''=A<1,?,''DocID''=56581,''DocVersion''=0>>')

SELECT Substring(col, Charindex(@Search, col) + Len(@Search),
              Charindex(',',
              REPLACE(col, '>', ','), Charindex(@Search, col)) - (
              Charindex(@Search, col) + Len(@Search) )) AS value
FROM   your_table
```

Comment: Thx for the answer.  I know that this table is violating the Normal Form, but it's a table of a database from another application.